# Can we implement some code that fires upon selecting something in google document?

Tags: google-apps-script

To be able to extend google docs, we need to have some event handling mechanism. I believe there are only a few supported in google docs. Is there a way We can write a function that triggers upon selecting content in a document ? not spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A script has been published when Google launched the ability to embed code in text document.

You should have a look at it as it might suit your needs : [cursor inspector](https://github.com/google/google-apps-script-samples/tree/master/cursor_inspector)

Comment: This is true and to be honest, It is known to me as well. My question arouse when I wanted a mechanism to write some script that opens a doc and acts on it, in others' environment when they wish to install my script. This somehow, indirectly solved my question. Though not satisfyingly. I click your answer as correct, as it solved my question "for now". (APPS-SCRIPT HAS A VAGUE DESIGN).